# D-BUS communication between lxc and host

Tags: dbus, lxc

I am recently made communication client-server app betweeen two diferent Linux users.
For that, I used system d-bus.
In direcory "/etc/dbus-1/system.d" I made configuration file for system d-bus and put in that directory.
In configuration file I set own two users on one d-bus interface.
After that, communication between two linux users it worked.

The my next step is accomplish a communication client-server app between host (my primarly user) and lxc container (based on ubuntu).
In that case, exists is one file system_bus_socket which is intended for host machine and exists second file system_bus_socket which intended for lxc machine.
My question is:
How to hook up on system_bus_socket (host machine) from lxc container?
I tried to mount dir from host /var/run/dbus to lxc /var/run/dbus, but it didn't work.

I hope that you understand me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a LXD proxy device to link a Unix socket on the host and a Unix socket in a container.

Here is how the command line should look like:

```
lxc config device add mycontainer mysocket proxy connect=unix:/var/on/the/host listen=unix:/var/in/the/container bind=container
```

Documentation: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/instances.md#type-proxy